# Open sets in Q wrt euclidean topology.

Tags: general-topology

What are the open sets in $\mathbb{Q}$ wrt euclidean topology?

Basically I want to know whether an arbitrary open set in a metric space is countable union of closed sets or not, with or without depending on the locally compactness of the metric space.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498266/open-set-in-a-metric-space-is-union-of-closed-sets

Comment: @Paquarian: No, it is not a duplicate: this question asks about the *countable* union of closed sets, whereas the other one asks about arbitrary unions (which is also why it has received a trivial answer). Please consider retracting your vote or, if the question gets closed by then, voting to reopen.

Comment: Hello $Alex M. I have not downvoted or closed the question. I simply just put a similar question in the comments section :)

Answer (score 0):

A space in which every open set is an $F_{\sigma}$ set ( a countable union of closed sets) is called a perfectly normal space.  Metric spaces are perfectly normal.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $U\subset X$ be open. For $n\in \mathbb N$ let $$V_n=\{p\in X: \forall q\in X \backslash U\;(\;d(p,q)\geq 1/n\;)\}.$$  (i). For each $p\in U$ there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ with $B_d(p,1/n)\subset U,$ so $p\in V_n$ for some $n\in \mathbb N.$ $$\text {So }\quad U\subset\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}V_n.$$  (ii). If $p\in X$ \ $U$ then   $p\not \in V_n $ for any $n$, because  there does exist $q\in X$ \ $U$ with $d(p,q)<1/n,$ namely $q=p.$ $$ \text {So } \quad U\supset \cup_{n\in \mathbb N}V_n.$$ $$\text {(iii). Therefore }\quad  U=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}V_n.$$ Each $V_n$ is closed. By contradiction, suppose $(p_j)_j$ is a sequence in $V_n$ converging to $x\not \in V_n.$ Then   there exists $q\in X$ \ $U$ with $r=d(p,q)<1/n.$ But there exists $j$ with $d(p_j,x)<((1/n)-r)/2,$ implying $$d(p_j,q)\leq d(p_j,x)+d(x,q)<((1/n)-r)/2+r=((1/n)+r)/2<1/n,$$ contradicting $p_j\in V_n.$

Comment: No, a $T_6$ space is a perfectly normal space that is also $T_1$ (equivalently, that is also Hausdorff). Singletons in a perfectly normal space need not be closed.